# Find 3D line equation in simplest form.

Tags: geometry

The line parallel to planes $-5x + y = 0$ and $x + 6y = 0,$ passes through the point $(3,0,2).$
My solution:.
Direction vector of the line:  $v (x,y,z).$
Orthogonal vectors of planes: $\;p_1(-5,1,0),\;   p_2(1,6,0).$
$v \cdot p_1 = |v| \cdot |p_1| \cdot \cos 90  = -5x + y = 0. \tag 1$ 
$v \cdot p_2 = |v| \cdot |p_2| \cdot \cos 90  =  x + 6y = 0. \tag 2$
Solve $(1)(2) => x = 0, \;y = 0.$
But answer in my book is $v(6, 30, -1).$
What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your book is using the planes $-5x+y=0$ and $x+6z=0$.  Notice that the second equation has replaced $y$ by $z$.

Comment: Your right. My eyes were fooled by my mind. It is caused by an interesting neurological phenomenon: BRAIN FILTERING.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong. In fact$$v=p_1\times p_2$$which shows the orthogonality therefore$$v=(-5\hat i+\hat j)\times (\hat i+6\hat j)=-31 \hat k$$hence the line is parallel to z-axis (which is expected) and the equation of the line would be$$\begin{cases}x=3\\y=0\\z=t\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! Your answer & mine are both right. Alter solve(1), (2), find out v = (0,0,t), I can conclude the line equation like yours.

Comment: Nice! Good luck!!